# Django ORM Query to join tables and then analyze

Tags: python, sql, django, django-orm

```
class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=30)


class Response(models.Model):
    answer = models.ForeignKey(Answer)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


class Profile(models.Model):
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('M', 'Male'),
        ('F', 'Female'),
    )
    user = models.OneToOneField("auth.User")
    age = models.IntegerField(max_length=2)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    zipcode = models.IntegerField(max_length=5)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=15)
```

I have a Response model that is answers to a question and a Profile model for each user and was wondering how to go about the query to get a list of each users answer (they are unique for each question for each user) and their profile info.  In the end I want to say what percentage of men answered one way vs another, how states voted, etc.  I am able to make a query to see what percentage of users voted for each question, but havent been able to break it down farther.  How would I make a query to find something like what percentage of an answer each gender voted for?

If i could join the Profile and Response tables on User I would be able to make a numpy array and analyze it like that, which I think would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Many-To-One Magic

Django provides convenience methods when any model has a `models.ForeignKey` field. See [Many-To-One Relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/) for more details. Check out this example to find `what percentage of an answer each gender voted for?`

Given a particular `Answer` as `answer`:

```
>>> answer.response_set.filter(user__profile__gender='M')
[<Repsonse 1>, <Repsonse 2>, <Repsonse 3>, ... ]
```

That will give you all of the responses where the user who answered was a male.

If you only want to know just the statistics and don't care about the actual Response objects returned, you can simply use the `.count()` method like this:

```
>>> queryset = answer.response_set.all()
>>> total_responses_for_answer = queryset.count()
>>> number_of_males = queryset.filter(user__profile__gender='M').count()
>>> print 'Percent', (number_of_males / float(total_responses_for_answer)) * 100
98.1
```

Let me try to explain what's going on.

### response_set.filter()

When `model B` has a `models.ForeignKey` field that points to `model A`, Django uses the `related_name` keyword argument to create a special method on `model A` that gets all relations in `model B` that point to the `model A` instance.

If the `related_name` keyword isn't specified, Django defaults the method name to `<relationship>_set`.

In this case, the `answer` field on the `Response` model did not specify the `related_name` keyword argument, so Django added the convenience method `response_set` on to the `Answer` model.

To see all `Responses` that chose `answer`, use the simple query:

```
>>> answer.response_set.all()
```

If you wanted, you could specify the `related_name` to create your own relationship method. For example:

```
class Response(models.Model):
    ...
    answer = models.ForeignKey(Answer, related_name='responses')
    ...

# and use the custom method name like so:
>>> answer = Answer.objects.get(pk=pk)
>>> answer.responses.all()
```

### filter(user_*profile*_gender='M')

The second bit of magic happening is the `JOINs` that you're looking for. The `response_set` returns a queryset of `Response` objects. The `Response` model has a field called `user`. The `Profile` model has a relationship to `User` via the `models.OneToOne` field `user` and the `Profile` model also contains that user's gender (and other fun stuff). The fancy double underscore part `user__profile__gender='M'` is simply saying:

> Find all **Response** instances **WHERE** the Response's user's __ profile's __ gender equals 'M'

Comment: So then would there be a way to get an output that would specify # of responses for M and # of responses for female for each answer? I am looking to do this for every answer within a question, so in the end I want to get something like:                                     Question: Coke or Pepsi --Answer:Coke (100 responses, 60M, 40F), Answer:Pepsi(50 responses,20M,30F).  I am trying to not do this by selecting the gender specifically(for this example), because I am also trying to do the same thing for states, zipcodes, age.

Comment: You'll want to take a look at Django's Aggregation API: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/. There you can issue queries that will retrieve the statistical information that you desire.